# Display problem with macbook pro mid 2015

Tags: macbook-pro

Recently my macbook pro 2015 has screen problem as the picture below.

Could anyone help me identy find the problem? [image]

Comment: Does it show up in screenshots? Does it happen in all programs, also when booting? If it doesn't show up in screenshots and shows up whatever you are doing (and from experience too) it is a hardware failure. To further rule out software issue run an apple hardware test, reset SMC and NVRAM/PRAM. If there is reason to believe it is a software fault, then you *could* try a clean install. However, I don't think its software related.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It doesn’t show up on screenshot or any apps except on main desktop screen and on browser the rest is ok. 

I expect the hardware malfunction too since I just clean up the machine recently and this happened when I open it again since I have 2nd one and has been using it ever since.

Comment: Thats weird. You are sure it does **not** show up in all other apps? Because if that is true, it would rule out a hardware issue. I would try to test as many apps as you can, with restarts in between, under extreme load (run something like HandBrake encoding) to see if it is heat related, check if it has to do with certain colors being displayed,...

Comment: Yes, have checked all regular apps, only happen on chrome and desktop itself.

Comment: Can you try with an external monitor? Also, try to change your background image. If you have a fast external USB/Thunderbolt drive you could try to install macOS there and boot from that drive, or do a clean install. And have you already tried the different startup modes? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the connectors to those columns of pixels are coming loose.

I had the same problem with a 2009 model MBP, about 1/2 the size of your problem and not at the very edge but in roughly the same position. It was intermittent at first but got worse over time until that column of pixels stopped displaying properly at all.

Apple would want to replace the top of the macbook. Possibly an electronics repair should could fix the cable instead of replacing the whole display section.